# Find the MLE say $\hat{\theta}$ and the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be iid sample from $X\sim f(x;\theta)=(\theta+1)x^\theta$ for $\theta>0$. Find the MLE say $\hat{\theta}$ and the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}$.

---

My work: The log-likelihood function is that
$$
\ell(\theta)=n\log(\theta+1)+\sum \theta\log X_i.
$$

The MLE is that
$$
\hat{\theta}=-\left(\frac{n}{\sum\log X_i}+1\right).
$$

Now, the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}$ should be
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta_0)\to N(0, I^{-1}(\theta_0))
$$
where $$I(\theta)=E\left[\left(\frac{\partial \ell(\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right].$$

Here $\hat{\theta}\to \theta$ in probability.

So the result is that $$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)\to N\left(0, \frac{(\theta+1)^2}{n}\right)$$?

Comment: closevoters, the OP is showing efforts at solving the problem.

Comment: @utobi they are probably voting to close because OP didn't have the tag, which implied they didn't read its wiki. The current consensus is to not add it for the OP

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Firebug.

Comment: A curiousity here is that $1/(\hat\theta+1)$ follows a Gamma distribution exactly with shape parameter $n$ and rate parameter $\theta+1$. So the distribution of $\hat\theta$ is known exactly and hence, except as an undergraduate math stat exercise, computing an asymptotic distibution using Fisher information is unnecessary.

Comment: Please specify the range of $X$; presumably $X\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your work is almost fine and a bit incomplete. To complete the answer you'll have to compute the Fisher information

\begin{align}
I_1(\theta) & = -E\left(\frac{d^2\ell(\theta;X_1)}{d\theta d\theta}\right)
\end{align}

where $\ell(\theta;X_1) = \log f(X_1;\theta)$, is the log-likelihood for a single observation, here chosen to be the first. You can also use its equivalent expression based on squared the score function, though that may lead to slightly longer computations.

**Remark** You can also use the asymptotically equivalent version based on the observed information $J(\theta) = -\frac{d^2\ell(\theta)}{d\theta d\theta}$. The rationale for this choice is that, under broad regularity conditions, $J(\theta)/n$ converges in probability to  $I_1(\theta)$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: So the result is that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)\to N(0, \frac{(\theta+1)^2}{n})$?

Comment: Y, but Without the n on the r.h.s

Answer (score 2):

So far so good. Just one thing you need to be careful with:

In your expression for the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta_0)$, the term $\mathcal{I}(\theta)$ is the information contained in a single observation.

I prefer the notation $\mathcal{I}_{X_1}(\theta)$ for this quantity, and $\mathcal{I}_{\mathbf{X}}(\theta) = n I_{X_1}(\theta)$ for the information contained in a random sample of size $n$.

Also, remember that there is an alternative formula for the Fisher information,
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\mathbf{X}}(\theta)= -\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \ell(\theta)\right)
$$
This is much easier to evaluate in this situation.

Comment: But what is $\theta_0$?

Comment: @Hermi, $\theta_0$ or $\theta\$ denotes the true parameter value.